# Linear Programming: Either OR constraint non-binary decision variables

Tags: linear-programming, constraints, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

I'm working on a production problem where I'm producing a number of products.  My decision variables indicate quantity levels of production across a range of prices.  My current LP solves for the optimal solution that maximizes revenue across products and prices, however I can only select one price.  For example in the equation below I have 3 prices multiplied by the decision variable $ x_{ij}$ where $\ i$ represents the product and$\ j$ maps to the corresponding price.
Note that there are varying levels of demand at each price point (constraints).  The trouble is that I can only select one price, therefore if $x_{11}$ is greater than 0 then $x_{12},\ x_{13}$ must BE zero.  I feel like there is a simple solution to this problem that I can't recall how to formulate it.  Most of what I can find is on binary (either or) constraints but these decision variables are not binary.  Maybe I need to reformulate the entire problem.  I would appreciate any help or references that may lead me to this solution.

$Max\ Z = 5x_{11} + 6x_{12} + 7x_{13} $

$s.t.$

$ x_{11} <= 50 $

$ x_{12} <= 40 $

$ x_{13} <= 30 $

**Constraint needed: if one decision variable is > 0 the others must be = 0**

Note: the solution to this specific problem is not relevant, just an simple example of the more elaborate demand varying problem.

Comment: This seems a very specific easy problem where $5\times 50 > 6 \times 40 > 7 \times 30$. Can you generalize this enough so that the "more elaborate" in your last line makes more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce three binary variables $y_{11}$, $y_{12}$, and $y_{13}$, together with linear constraints
\begin{align}
0 \le x_{11} &\le 50 y_{11} \\
0 \le x_{12} &\le 40 y_{12} \\
0 \le x_{13} &\le 30 y_{13} \\
y_{11} + y_{12} + y_{13} &\le 1
\end{align}
For example $x_{11} > 0$ implies $y_{11} = 1$, which implies $y_{12} = 0$, which implies $x_{12} = 0$, as desired.  The other cases are similarly verified.

Comment: thank you so much.  I thought to add the y variable yesterday but didn't add it to the demand constraints (I tried multiplying in the obj function).  Your approach worked perfectly.  I can't thank you enough!